# How to enumerate folders in a directory and populate a ComboBox using VB

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I am a new VB.Net programmer using Visual Studio 2015.

I need to enumerate a set of folders in a path and use those folder names to populate a ComboBox so that I can select that folder with my application.

The folders will have an identifier such as -

\Folder1.kma
\Folder2.kma
\Folder3.kma
\Folder4.kma

I only want folders with the .kma extension to be used to populate the ComboBox. All other folders will be ignored.

How do I locate just those folders?
How do I use the results to populate the ComboBox?

Comment: Did you search here for `vb.net enumerate files` or `vb.net get files in dir`? There are dozens of existing questions. There are also dozens of questions asking how to add items to a combobox. Please make a basic effort to find existing questions before posting a new one. You can then use that information to at least make an effort to solve the problem yourself, and have some code to include if you run into difficulty and need to ask for help. You'll also have a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Dim di As New DirectoryInfo("C:/")
   Dim diar As FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*kma")
   Dim dra As FileInfo
        For Each dra In diar
           ComboBox1.Items.Add(dra)
        Next
```

This gets all the .kma files in "C:/" folder.